# Dozens of Ubuntu One conflict files

Tags: ubuntu-one

I work with a drawing program and every ten minutes I store the changes. Automatically, besides the drawing file, a backup `file.bak` is created, or updated, storing the former status. This is the expected behavior. My computer synchronizes the drawing files on Ubuntu One. Although those were not opened by other computers connected to the same account at the same time, the backup-file produces a `file.bak.u1conflict` file. After some time of work there are dozens of conflict files in the folder, and I have to delete them manually.

Why does this happen and how could I solve this? Would it be possible to prevent certain filetypes from being synchronized or delete them automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation about Ubuntu One conflicts: https://askubuntu.com/a/329495/61416

You can ignore some files and Ubuntu One will not sync them. [Here is how you do that](https://askubuntu.com/a/154177/61416).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me to solve this. I didn't know that it is possible to exlude files from syncing. Altough, I don't know why this conflict happens, because nobody opens my files at the same time.